# How to hide div onclick in unordered List 

Tags: javascript

In an onclick event, I would like to hide the "closed" `li` and show the "open" and vice versa.
can I do this in Javascript?

I have the following html:

```
<ul>
<li> link</li>
<li> Liink</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here or what your html structure is like. Can you post some html pseudocode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jquery.

And then use:

```
$('li').toggle();
```